# Leak around window

Tags: water, windows, leak, window-frame

Currently renovating our new home. We have a leak around in the bottom two corners of the window. We are unsure if this is from the window itself or elsewhere.
We have resealed the outside of the window, repointed the bricks surrounding the window and resealed the inside of the window but it is still letting water in.
Unsure of our next step[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the structure upstair, another floor or roof?

Comment: Some joinery has drainage holes in the frame.  Look in the bottom of the frames.  maybe they are clogged.